Translation of bounded set in TVS is bounded
I need to use the fact that, if $X$ is a TVS and $A \subseteq X$ is a (von Neumann) bounded set, then $x + A$ is bounded for any $x \in X$. This seems obvious and Wikipedia says its true and points to Lawrence Narisci and Edward Beckenstein's Topological Vector Spaces, but I can't find a proof of this in that book.
Even though the definition of bounded sets talks about neighbourhood of zeros, it seems to me that this property is independent of the "choice of the origin", which would be the same thing as the translation of a bounded set being bounded.
I can't seem to put together a rigorous proof of all this. Could you help me with this? I can prove that if $U$ is a convex neighbourhood of 0, then its translations are bounded since its Minkowski functional is sublinear, so translations of a bounded set are absorved by inflations of convex neighborhoods of 0, but I need to extend this to nonconvex neighbourhoods. This is enough for locally convex TVSs, but it's possible to prove for spaces that aren't locally convex, right? I'm sure I'm just missing some simple tool to use here but it's not clicking right now.
In the exceptional case that this isn't true for some pathological TVS, please show me an example and then edit the Wikipedia.

Nevermind, my bad, Narisci and Beckenstein's proves that finite Minkowski sums of bounded sets are bounded and a translation of a bounded set is the Minkowski sum of the set and the point by which we translate, so the proof by Narisci and Beckenstein's is enough:
Let $A$ be a bounded set, $x \in X$ and $U$ be a neighbourhood of 0 and choose $V$ another neighbourhood of 0 such that $V+V \subseteq U$. Then there is a $r>0$ such that $x \in rV$ and $A \subseteq rV$. Then $x+A \subseteq rV + rV \subseteq rU$ and $x+A$ is bounded.

+1, but it would be more elegant to derive their 2nd statement (about $x+A$) from the 1st one (about $A+B$). Also, correct (twice) the authors' names: Narisci and Beckenstein.

@AnneBauval thank you! my bad again, I read their names the other way around since i was typing all this on my phone
